# How to access audio file from the google cloud storage?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to access the audio file(https://storage.cloud.google.com/grad_production/SineWaveMinus16.wav) from the google file storage  in the html audio tag.
How to access the file in the angular 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can find two issues.

1. You can play audio in angular using standard HTML control

```
<audio controls src={{filetoplay}}></audio>
```

2. Do you have problems with permissions? When I try download your file it returns 403 http error (Forbidden). If so, You need to set rules on your storage account, for example:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      // allow access for all users
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

You can setup this in firebase console -> Storage -> Rules.

Comment: yes, facing the same issue .unable to access file in the browser